# Merging two list in optimize way

Tags: java

I have two list.

```
List<Customer> customers1 = getCustomerDetails1();
List<Customer> customers2 = getCustomerDetails2();

public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private String birthDate;
    private String formatedDob;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String oldMobileNumber;
    private String emailId;
    private String add1;
    private String add2;
    private String add3;
    private String pincode;
    private String city;
    private String cityId;

    ----
    getter, setter
```

NOw I am merging both list data as below:

```
List<Customer> customerVoList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Customer localCustomerVO : customers1) {
    for (Customer customerHubVO : customers2) {
        localCustomerVO = fillCustomerDetails(localCustomerVO, customerHubVO);
        customerVoList.add(localCustomerVO);
    }
}

private Customer fillCustomerDetails(Customer localCustomerVO, Customer customerHuvVO) {
        localCustomerVO.setFirstName(StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getFirstName()) ? localCustomerVO.getFirstName() : customerHuvVO.getFirstName());
        localCustomerVO.setLastName(StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getLastName()) ? localCustomerVO.getLastName() : customerHuvVO.getLastName());
        localCustomerVO.setEmailId(StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getEmailId()) ? localCustomerVO.getEmailId() : customerHuvVO.getEmailId());
        localCustomerVO.setBirthDate(StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getBirthDate()) ? localCustomerVO.getBirthDate() : customerHuvVO.getBirthDate());
        localCustomerVO.setFormatedDob(customerHuvVO.getBirthDate() != null ? DateUtils.getDateddMMYYYY(customerHuvVO.getBirthDate()) : (localCustomerVO.getBirthDate() != null ? DateUtils.getDateddMMYYYY(localCustomerVO.getBirthDate()) : ""));

        localCustomerVO.setAdd1(StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getAdd1()) ? localCustomerVO.getAdd1() : customerHuvVO.getAdd1());
        localCustomerVO.setAdd2(StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getAdd2()) ? localCustomerVO.getAdd2() : customerHuvVO.getAdd2());
        localCustomerVO.setAdd3(StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getAdd3()) ? localCustomerVO.getAdd3() : customerHuvVO.getAdd3());
        localCustomerVO.setCity(StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getCity()) ? localCustomerVO.getCity() : customerHuvVO.getCity());
        localCustomerVO.setState(StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getState()) ? localCustomerVO.getState() : customerHuvVO.getState());
        localCustomerVO.setPincode(StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getPincode()) ? localCustomerVO.getPincode() : customerHuvVO.getPincode());

        return localCustomerVO;
}
```

Above codes are working fine. But I am looking for other best way.

Comment: This looks wrong. Shouldn't you be merging one customer of the first list with exactly one corresponding customer of the second list?

Comment: What is `CustomerVO`?

Comment: @Eran It is just a very easy way to increase your revenue. You had `N` customers before, now you have `N^2` customers instead :D

Comment: suggest any better way

Comment: It's not clear from the question _what_ you mean by merging (i.e. what the result should be), and how you expect it to be better (faster?; less code?; more idiomatic?).

Comment: I did not understanding how you are merging .You are taking customer 1 and copy some value in customer 2 ,Total list count will be No of customer1*No of customer2 .

Comment: @Eran Your comment is not clear. Can plz explain more?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty You seem to be merging each customer with all the other customers. I'm assuming the correct behavior would be to match each customer of the first list to a customer of the second list (perhaps by comparing customer ID or something similar), and only merge pairs of matching customers.

Answer (score 0):

If indeed you want simply to match record #0 of `customers1` with record #0 of `customers2`, record #1 of `customers1` with record #1 of `customers2`, etc., do something like this:

```
Iterator<Customer> iter1 = customers1.iterator();
Iterator<Customer> iter2 = customers2.iterator();
while (iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext()) {
    Customer cust1 = iter1.next();
    Customer cust2 = iter2.next();
    customerVoList.add(localCustomerVO);
}
```

I'd ask you to consider the possibility that this might not really be what you have in mind, but if it is, that's basically how you'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

You check if customerHuvVO property is empty, and if so you set the value of the property of localCustomerVO to the same value which is unnecessary.

So instead of writing:

`localCustomerVO.setFirstName(StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getFirstName()) ? localCustomerVO.getFirstName() : customerHuvVO.getFirstName());`

you can write:

`if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(customerHuvVO.getFirstName())) localCustomerVO.setFirstName(customerHuvVO.getFirstName());`

and so eliminate the unnecessary update.

And you should also check your logic as @Eran pointed out.